# What does this Entity Framework Core exception mean?

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-core

To setup the exception message here is some code.

In my Repository class I have the following code:

```
public async Task<CoverLetterBank> GetCoverLetterBankAsync(int clBankID)
{
    IQueryable<CoverLetterBank> query = BankContext.CoverLetterBanks.Include(c => c.CoverLetters).Include(d => d.CoverLetterCategories);

    return await query.FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.Id == clBankID);
}

public async Task<IEnumerable<CoverLetterBank>> GetCoverLetterBanksAsync()
{
    return await BankContext.CoverLetterBanks.ToListAsync(); ;
}
```

The GetCoverLettersBanksAsync() call works.  However, when I call the GetCoverLetterBankAsync() method I get the following exception:

"   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowNotSupportedException(ExceptionResource resource)\r\n   at System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection`1.System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<T>.Add(T value)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.ClrICollectionAccessor`3.Add(Object entity, Object value, Boolean forMaterialization)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.AddToCollection(INavigation navigation, InternalEntityEntry value, Boolean forMaterialization)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalMixedEntityEntry.AddToCollection(INavigation navigation, InternalEntityEntry value, Boolean forMaterialization)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.NavigationFixer.AddToCollection(InternalEntityEntry entry, INavigation navigation, InternalEntityEntry value, Boolean fromQuery)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.NavigationFixer.SetReferenceOrAddToCollection(InternalEntityEntry entry, INavigation navigation, InternalEntityEntry value, Boolean fromQuery)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.NavigationFixer.ToDependentFixup(InternalEntityEntry dependentEntry, InternalEntityEntry principalEntry, IForeignKey foreignKey, Boolean fromQuery)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.NavigationFixer.InitialFixup(InternalEntityEntry entry, Boolean fromQuery)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.NavigationFixer.TrackedFromQuery(InternalEntityEntry entry)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntryNotifier.TrackedFromQuery(InternalEntityEntry entry)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.MarkUnchangedFromQuery()\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.StartTrackingFromQuery(IEntityType baseEntityType, Object entity, ValueBuffer& valueBuffer)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryContext.StartTracking(IEntityType entityType, Object entity, ValueBuffer valueBuffer)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.CustomShaperCompilingExpressionVisitor.g__ProcessCurrentElementRow|9_0TIncludingEntity,TIncludedEntity\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.CustomShaperCompilingExpressionVisitor.PopulateIncludeCollection[TIncludingEntity,TIncludedEntity](Int32 collectionId, QueryContext queryContext, DbDataReader dbDataReader, ResultCoordinator resultCoordinator, Func3 parentIdentifier, Func`3 outerIdentifier, Func`3 selfIdentifier, Func`5 innerShaper, INavigation inverseNavigation, Action`2 fixup, Boolean trackingQuery)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.CustomShaperCompilingExpressionVisitor.g__ProcessCurrentElementRow|9_0TIncludingEntity,TIncludedEntity\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.CustomShaperCompilingExpressionVisitor.PopulateIncludeCollection[TIncludingEntity,TIncludedEntity](Int32 collectionId, QueryContext queryContext, DbDataReader dbDataReader, ResultCoordinator resultCoordinator, Func3 parentIdentifier, Func`3 outerIdentifier, Func`3 selfIdentifier, Func`5 innerShaper, INavigation inverseNavigation, Action`2 fixup, Boolean trackingQuery)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Collections.Generic.LargeArrayBuilder`1.AddRange(IEnumerable`1 items)\r\n   at System.Collections.Generic.EnumerableHelpers.ToArray[T](IEnumerable`1 source)\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)\r\n   at System.Linq.SystemCore_EnumerableDebugView`1.get_Items()"

Here are the frameworks and packages:

[image]

Comment: The exception (which as you can see is not by EF Core) means that `CoverLetters` and/or `CoverLetterCategories` collection navigation property is backed with **read only** collection, hence EF Core cannot populate it.

Comment: @IvanStoev Thanks - how would I find that out?